# Why does returning an int in a method that should return a short work?

Tags: java

```
static void method(short x)
{
   //do some stuff
}
```

When I called above method from `main` method using the following line.

```
method(1); // compilation failed
```

I know above calling is invalid because parameter 'x' is expecting short and we are passing int.

I further tested the above concept and coded another method:

```
static short method()
{
    //do some stuff
    return 1;    
}
```

but above method works fine, where return type is short and we are returning int.
Why does the second method compile?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The [`return` statement (JLS 14.17)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.17) is able to use an [assignment conversion (JLS 5.2)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.2) to convert from the original expression type to the return type.

Assignment conversion includes the ability to convert a constant expression to a narrower type if it's in the range of the target type. So a constant expression of type `int` can be converted to `short` when the value is in the range of `short`.

Method arguments don't go through assignment conversion - they only use method [invocation conversion (JLS 5.3)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.3) which *doesn't* include this constant conversion.

In terms of *why* this happens - I suspect it just makes things simpler to reason about. Assignment conversions always have a *single* target type - whereas in the case of method arguments, there may be various different overloads to consider, so there'd have to be more rules to determine how specific a constant expression conversion would be. That's just a guess though - and it clearly *could* be done. (C# allows this, for example.)

Comment: I should have know that I need not dig into the JLS. Waiting for you to answer is quicker ;-) This opens the interesting question: *Why* have they chosen this inconsistency?

Answer (score 3):

Your value happens to fit in a short. Try return something that doesn't fit in 16 bits, like a integer value larger than 32767 and you will get a compile time error.

Comment: Actually, it would be 32768 since the range of a short is -2^15 to 2^15-1.

Comment: @PharfarFystok: It doesn't just get truncated in the same way as a cast would - if you try to return a constant expression which isn't in the right range, you'll get a compile-time error.

Comment: @JonSkeet I see. Thanks for clearing that up. I'll make an update.

Answer (score 0):

There shouldn't be an issue with any Number within the range of  **-32,768** and a *maximum* value of **32,767**

Actually you can use a `short` to save memory in large *arrays*, in situations where the 
*memory savings* actually matters.

In comparison, the `int` data type is a 32-bit signed two's complement integer. It has a minimum value of **-2,147,483,648** and a maximum value of **2,147,483,647**. For integral values, this data type is generally the default choice unless there is a reason *(i.e Memory savings)* to choose something else. This data type will most likely be large enough for the numbers your program will use, but if you need a wider range of values, use `long` instead.